# Stop iframe from interfering with hash link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a project where I have an iframe with a form that needs to be accessible, but also there's a section lower on the page with information that's hashlinked

you can see a jsfiddle to get an idea of the rough structure.

http://jsfiddle.net/jz2rsxLb/2/

```
<div><iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe></div>
<div id="blue">BLAH BLAH BLAH</div>
```

Basically, whenever someone goes to site/#blue, it loads to the correct location briefly, then when the iframe and form in the iframe load, it springs the page back up to the iframe suddenly.  I need to turn off this behavior.  Any ideas?

Comment: A working example with the issue to see in action would be good. BTW iframe and accessibility may not be possible.

Comment: Please see here: http://pro.steadfastlight.com/residential/#energy-saving

Comment: Which browser? I seem to don't have this problem in current Chrome